# Handle exceptions from WS

Tags: c#, web-services, client-server

I've WS client written in C#. Is there any way I can handle all exceptions in one place? Now WS methods are executed in many places so I have to write many try...catch to handle them all.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to handle exceptions generated from a WS call on client? what kind of client is it? is this Windows Forms... WPF... Javascript..

Comment: It's WinForms application. I don't mean exceptions generated by WS. I want to handle exceptions like this thrown when is some problem with connection. Of course would be great if I could handle exceptions thrown by WS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

before creating winform, you need to add this line

```
 Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use svcutil.exe (In Visual Studio: "Add Service Reference") to generate a WCF client, even if it is just a plain old (asmx) web service. Then you can inject your own implementation of the IErrorHandler interface. In this case you just need to provide an implementation of IErrorHandler.HandleError since the ProvideFault method would only be used on the service side.